# Mongo Match number that "begins with" query in an array of numbers

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query

in the mongo shell I am trying to query into an array of numbers

An example object:

```
[{"name":"test", "numbers" : [76.3922, 42.9196154]}, 
{"name":"test", "numbers" : [87.938547, 42.9196154]},
{"name":"test", "numbers" : [42.9196154,87.938547]}]
```

I tried to use this to find any document what the number starts with 87

```
db.TestColleciton.find( { "numbers": { $in: [ /^-87/ ] } } )
```

Comment: Do you mean the first number in the `numbers` array? Also your regex will not work if those element in `numbers` are float point number. To use regex you array elements must be string.

Comment: Your regex also has a negative sign in it so it would only match `-87`, is that what you want?

Comment: @user3100115 True. So the solution here is either to look at "stringifying" the numeric value, or better yet consider all the possible values in a "range" for what the number is meant to "begin with". Depending on the precision of what that means.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two misunderstandings in your approach here. The first is that regular expressions only ever work with strings and not with numeric values. JavaScript is an example of one language implementation that will "stringify" the numeric value for comparison, but that is the basic process. More later.

The other misunderstanding seems to be the use of [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in). You don't need that operator "just" to perform a test on an array element, but rather it is the other way around, where you can supply an array of values to test against a field ( either a single value or an array ). This is basically a shorthand form of an [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) condition for testing multiple values on the same field. Since there is only one value to test, you likely don't need it here.

If your intent is to match documents that "start with" the "87" value, then you can use JavaScript evaluation of [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/). Though it's not the most optimal thing to do, since an index cannot be employed in the matching and the function supplied must be tested by brute force against the whole collection, or at least the result of other query arguments:

```js
db.TestCollection.find(
    function() {
        return this.numbers.some(function(el) {
            return /^87/.test(el);
        });
    }
)
```

Directly supplying a `function` argument to `.find()` is a shell "shorcut" for `$where`, but you can also use the long form with any string that provides a JavaScript expression to return `true/false`. Also noting that the caret `^` is the correct element to use for "starts with" in a regular expression. JavaScript "stringifies" here, so the test will return true.

But a better case for using natural query operators here would be more performant, basically looking for all values between `87` and `88`. This will return all floating point variations in an efficient way:

```js
db.TestCollection.find({
    "numbers": { "$gte": 87, "$lt": 88 }
})
```

So the [`$gte`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/) and [`$lt`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/lt/) operators bound the range for all possible floating point combinations begining with `87` in the most efficient way. And of course you just need to apply the array element to test and all elements will be inpected.

So when looking for numbers that "begin with", then it is always better to look at the numeric "range" consideration rather than resorting to regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Refer to [this](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1174)

> MongoDB regular expression capabilities for pattern matching *strings* in queries. We've thought about this, but don't think allowing regex against non string fields is a great idea. It will be very slow, and kind of misleading.

We can do it through [$where](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/)

```
> db.TestColleciton.find({$where: 'return this.numbers.some(function(n){ return /^87.*/.test(n);})'})
```